# Dynamically limiting Inline Model Fields shown in Django admin

Tags: django, dynamic, django-admin, inline-formset

I'm trying to exclude certain fields ('item_1', 'item_2') from being shown from my model based on the value of another field ('configuration'). The model is featured as an inline in the Django admin. I've tried the code below but nothing changes in the admin. The detection of the value of 'configuration' seems to work but not the exclusion. As a side note I'm using the Django Suit admin skin.

```
class LayoutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LayoutForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        configuration = self.instance.configuration
        if configuration == '2d':
            class Meta:
                exclude = ['item_1','item_2']

class LayoutInline(SortableTabularInline):
    model = Layout
    sortable = 'order'
    extra = 0
    form = LayoutForm

class ModuleAdmin(SortableModelAdmin):
    inlines = [LayoutInline]

admin.site.register(Module,ModuleAdmin)
```

Comment: class Meta in __init__ may be a "local class", not working as what you want it to be

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm sure you're right. I'm just trying to figure out what the correct alternative is...if I put the Meta in the LayoutForm where it should be I can't seem to influence it in any way.

Comment: Meta is a class in class, so `self.configuration` won't work in Meta class, but if you use `pickle` may be a solution, maybe 'StringIO` is better to get self.confiuration, without write data to hard disk